# executing code only once outside a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

can anybody help me please to make sure the **API_Duplicate** outside of the while loops only runs once?

My methodology is:

for `while MarketIsActive == 'True'` to run continuously, listening for updates and assigning it to **API_Data**.

outside of the while loop, the `API_duplicate = API_Data` only needs to execute the once to assign its value.

this allows the second while loop, `while API_Duplicate != API_Data` to perform and take over the responsibility of assigning the `API_duplicate = API_Data` within the loop itself.

```
while MarketIsActive == 'True':
    API_data = 'API_endpoint'

API_duplicate = API_Data

    while API_Duplicate != API_Data
        API_duplicate = API_Data

        # extra code
```

Thank you.

Comment: your code has indentation errors

Comment: I wrote it like that because I didn't want the duplicate to update itself more than once, so I thought it would be best to exclude it from the first while loop

Comment: use if condition `if API_Duplicate != API_Data`

Comment: an if statement wouldn't execute because the "API_Duplicate" assignment is still executing before it?

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside a class, have the class have a count variable, and assign `API_duplicate` via a setter method, something like:

```
def set_dup(self):
    if self.count < 1:
        self.API_duplicate=self.API_data
        self.count +=1
```

Comment: thank you for solving this  issue, but the second while loop does not identify the API_duplicate.